# trying to execute s3-sqs qubole connector for spark structured streaming

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, qubole

I am trying to follow, https://github.com/qubole/s3-sqs-connector and trying to load the connector but seems like the connector is not available on maven and while generating the buiold manually the sqs classes are not loaded.
Can some1 guide me on this.

Thanks,
Dipesh

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

S3-SQS connector is now released on maven central.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qubole/spark-sql-streaming-sqs

You should be able to use it now. Get back to us if you face any problems.

---

Unfortunately, registration of the s3-sqs-connector in spark-packages is still pending. We'll try to release the package in maven central directly as soon as possible but it should take a few days at the very least.

In the meantime, you can clone the repository and build the jar yourself if required.